# Meteor SimpleSchema insert with nested object

Tags: mongodb, meteor, simple-schema

I have the following collection which has a nested object `address` which is defined using the [Collection2](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-collection2) Meteor Package. I am unable to insert the data for this nested object...

**Sample data**

```
var addresses = [{
    "venue": "Kirkstall Abbey",
    "street": "Kirkstall Lane",
    "city": "Leeds",
    "county": "West Yorkshire",
    "postcode": "LS6 3LF"
},{ 
    "venue": "Headingley High School",
    "street": "",
    "city": "Leeds",
    "county": "West Yorkshire",
    "postcode": "LS6 7QR"
}];


var locations = [{
    "name": "Kirkstall Abbey",
    "address": addresses[0],
    "image": null,
    "active": true
},{
    "name": "Headingley",
    "address": addresses[1],
    "image": null,
    "active": true
}];
```

**Collection definition**

```
ClassLocation = new Mongo.Collection("class-location");

Schemas.ClassLocation = new SimpleSchema({
    name: {
      type: String,
      optional: true
    },
    address: {
      type: Object
    },
    image: {
      type: String,
      optional: true
    }
    active: {
      type: Boolean,
      optional: true
    }
});

ClassLocation.attachSchema(Schemas.ClassLocation);
```

**Routine**

```
if(ClassLocation.find().count() === 0) {
  _.each(locations, function (location) {
    console.log(location.address);
    ClassLocation.insert(location);
  });
}
```

**The Problem**

The console logs out the location address details object fine but, my MongoDb collection of inserted documents is empty for address? I've tried a multitude of things, including doing an update after the initial insert (which is far from ideal).

Can anyone explain why this nested object isn't being inserted and what is required to fix it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the **[publish-counts](https://github.com/percolatestudio/publish-counts)** package to subscribe a count in meteor:

```
// server: publish the current size of a collection
Meteor.publish('getLocationCounts', function() {
    Counts.publish(this, 'locations-counter', ClassLocation.find());
});
```

Once you've subscribed to 'getLocationCounts', you can call `Counts.get('locations-counter')` to get the value of the counter, reactively.

This function will always return an integer, 0 is returned if the counter is neither published nor subscribed to.

```
// client: get the count value reactively
var exists = (Counts.get('locations-counter')=== 0);
if(exists) {
    _.each(locations, function (location) {
        console.log(location.address);
        ClassLocation.insert(location);
    });
}
```

Comment: @chridam...how did you become so well versed in MongoDB? I'm trying to grow. I wish I could ask you a few questions,in a chat or something.

Comment: @inspired Mostly reading the main MongoDB documentation, blogs, JIRA, github and of course the growing MongoDB University online courses. Drop me a gmail with the same handle.

Comment: @chridam the problem isn't the `find().count()`, the issue is the inserted location address field is null (0 fields).

Comment: I believe the issue is not on inserting but on how you are using `find().count()` which is reactive to insert.

Comment: @chridam I sent you a gmail message. Thanks.

Comment: @chridam thanks but I have tried exactly what you have suggested here and address is still not populated. Is there anything else you can suggest?

Comment: @chridam also, interestingly the 'exists' flag is always true even after I see some documents have been inserted. :-/

Comment: @MattWebb I could suggest implementing a reactive count like the meteor [docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_publish) "count-by-room" example.